# product of nonsingular polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, harmonic-analysis

In $R^n$, the polynomial $P$ is called nonsingular if $0$ is its regular value i.e. $\forall x  s.t. p(x)=0,\mbox{then} \nabla  p(x)\neq0$.

How to prove that the product of nonsingular polynomials has the property that its nonsingular points are dense in its zero set?

I have seen this property on Guth,s paper of polynomial partition. But I think it is wrong. If $$p1=p2=x,p=p1\cdot p2=x^2$$
It only has one singular point $0$ in zero set.
So, something must be wrong.

Comment: are you sure that in the product the polynomials have the same variable? Because it seems true to me when you multiply nonsingular $p(x)$, $q(y)$

Comment: I afraid that the polynomials have the same variable. you can read the corollary 1.7 of the paper  'A RESTRICTION ESTIMATE USING POLYNOMIAL PARTITIONING'. We always work in the same space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is wrong usually. But if we ask the polynomials are prime to each other, the question is true. And in the paper of Guth, we can ask this property by the prime factorization of the product.Then delete the power.